# Breqn+Babel can't handle minus signs

Tags: babel, breqn

I can't get this to compile:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage[czech]{babel}
\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}
-
\end{document}
```

This is the error I'm receiving:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.7 -
```

Comment: Load `breqn` before `babel`. or better use `\shorthandoff{-}` after `\begin{document}`

Comment: @HarishKumar Switching loading order helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package `breqn` works by making *math active* several characters, among which the hyphen.

This means that it provides a definition for `-` as an active character, but *doesn't* activate it; it rather assigns it the special mathcode `"8000` and TeX knows that, when it finds `-` in math mode, it has to use its definition as an active character.

However this conflicts with `babel-czech` which *does* activate the hyphen as a shorthand.

What happens in your test document is that between the two definitions of `-` as an active character, the one of `breqn` wins, because it's loaded later. Changing the order of the packages should work, because `babel` knows that it has to deliver an ordinary (non active) hyphen when the active `-` is found in math mode and `babel` (differently from `breqn`) takes care to save a definition of `-` as active character when doing its initializations, so the ordinary `-` is translated correctly according to the setup in `breqn`.

In conclusion,

```
\documentclass{article} 

\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}
```

is the correct order.

---

Here's the experiment proving the claims above. By compiling

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage[czech]{babel}

\begin{document}
$a$ % just for avoiding math initialization

\begingroup\tracingmacros=1
$a-b$
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

I get this in the `.log` file (line numbers added for reference).

```
322 -->\active@prefix -\normal@char- 
323 
324 \active@prefix #1->\ifx \protect \@typeset@protect \else \ifx \protect \@unexpa
325 ndable@protect \noexpand #1\else \protect #1\fi \expandafter \@gobble \fi 
326 #1<--
327 
328 \normal@char- ->\textormath {-}{\csname bbl@oridef@@-\endcsname }
329 
330 \textormath ->\ifmmode \expandafter \@secondoftwo \else \expandafter \@firstoft
331 wo \fi 
332 
333 \@secondoftwo #1#2->#2
334 #1<--
335 #2<-\csname bbl@oridef@@-\endcsname 
336 
337 \bbl@oridef@@- ->\@sym -\math_sym_Bin:Nn \mg@bin {00}
```

Line 322 shows that the `babel` definition of `-` is used. Then `\textormath` enters into action and, since the hyphen appears in math mode,

```
\csname bbl@oridef@@-\endcsname
```

is called (lines 328–335) and line 337 proves that the definition of `-` in `breqn` is used.